# Specifying the location of an inlineshape in MS Word (VBA)

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

I've been trying to adapt the method shown here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246299 so that I can create a command button in word which will save the document and remove itself when clicked. I've been unable to figure out how to change the position of the button from the default of the top left of the first page however. Ideally I'd like the button to be generated at the end of the document and be centre aligned, or otherwise placed at the cursor position.

Any advice would be very much appreciated :)

Thank You.

My VB.NET project code so far:

```
Dim shp As Word.InlineShape

shp = wrdDoc.Content.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")

shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Save To Disk"

shp.Width = "100"

'Add a procedure for the click event of the inlineshape

Dim sCode As String

sCode = "Private Sub " & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_Click()" & vbCrLf & _

"ActiveDocument.SaveAs(""" & sOutFile & """)" & vbCrLf & _

"On Error GoTo NoSave" & vbCrLf & _

"MsgBox ""Document Saved Successfully""" & vbCrLf & _

"Dim o As Object" & vbCrLf & _

"For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes" & vbCrLf & _

"If o.OLEFormat.Object.Name = ""CommandButton1"" Then" & vbCrLf & _

"o.Delete" & vbCrLf & _

"End If" & vbCrLf & _

"Next" & vbCrLf & _

"Exit Sub" & vbCrLf & _

"NoSave:" & vbCrLf & _

"MsgBox ""Document Failed To Save""" & vbCrLf & _

"End Sub"

wrdDoc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)

wrdApp.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as everything else is working just set the shp.left = 250 and shp.top = 1200

etc etc.

Just like in VB when you place a button.  For more details on the exact calls you should reference this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh965406%28v=office.14%29.aspx

But say to center a button you can set left to be the (doc.width - shape.width)

But word buttons allow for much more complex styling and setup.